# kubelet restarting randomly

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubelet

We have a 2 nodes cluster running on GKE and for a long time we have been suffering random downtimes due what appears as kubelet service random restarts.

These are the logs for the last downtime in the node that was running the kubernetes system pods at that time:

`sudo journalctl -r -u kubelet`

```
Aug 22 04:17:36 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:17:36 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:17:36 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 22 04:10:46 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:10:46 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:10:46 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 22 04:09:48 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:09:46 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:09:44 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 22 04:02:05 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:02:03 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:02:03 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 22 04:01:09 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:01:09 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: Stopped Kubernetes kubelet.
Aug 22 04:01:08 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 22 04:00:58 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 22 04:00:58 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Unit entered failed state.
Aug 22 04:00:58 gke-app-node1 systemd[1]: kubelet.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 22 04:00:58 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:58.104306    1330 server.go:794] GET /healthz: (5.286840082s) 200 [[curl/7.51.0] 127.0.0.1:35924]
Aug 22 04:00:58 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:57.981923    1330 docker_server.go:73] Stop docker server
Aug 22 04:00:58 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:53.991354    1330 server.go:794] GET /healthz: (5.834296581s) 200 [[Go-http-client/1.1] 127.0.0.1:35926]
Aug 22 04:00:57 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:42.636036    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 16.466105259s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/e496194dfcb8a053050a0eb73965f57b109fe3036c1ffc5b0f12b4a341f13794 /var/lib/docker/containers/b6a212aedf588a1f1d173fd9f4871f678d014e260e8aa6147ad8212619675802]
Aug 22 04:00:39 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:38.061492    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 12.246559762s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/303dc4c5814a0a12a6ac450e5b27327f55a7baa8000c011bd38521f3ff997e0f /var/lib/docker/containers/18a95beaf86b382bb8abc6ee40033020de1da4b54a5ca52e1c61bf7f14d6ef44]
Aug 22 04:00:39 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:38.476930    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 11.766408434s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/86802dda255243388ab86fa8fc403187193f8c4ccdee54d8ca18c021ca35bc36 /var/lib/docker/containers/7fd4d507ec6445035fcb4a60efd4ae68e54052c1cace3268be72954062fed830]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:35.865293    1330 prober.go:106] Readiness probe for "web-deployment-812924635-ntcqw_default(bcf76fb6-8661-11e7-88da-42010a840211):rails-app" failed (failure): Get http://10.48.1.7:80/health_check: net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: W0822 04:00:35.380953    1330 prober.go:98] No ref for container "docker://e2dcca90c091d2789af9b22e1405cb273f63c399aecde2686ef4b1e8ab9fdc5f" (web-deployment-812924635-ntcqw_default(bcf76fb6-8661-11e7-88da-42010a840211):rails-app)
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:32.514573    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 7.127181023s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/647f419bce585a3d0f5792376b269704cb358828bc5c4fb5e815bfa23950d511 /var/lib/docker/containers/59f7ada601f38a243daa7154f2ed27790d14d163c4675e26186d9a6d9db0272e]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:32.255644    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.72357089s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/992a65b68531c5ac53e4cd06f7a8f8abe4b908d943b5b9cc38da126b469050b2 /var/lib/docker/containers/2be7aede380d6f3452a5abacc53f9e0a69f8c5ee3dbdf5351a30effdf2d47833]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:32.067601    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.511405985s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/7bc4e00d232b4a22eb64a87ad079970aabb24bde17d3adaa6989840ebc91b96c /var/lib/docker/containers/949c778861a4f86440c5dd21d4daf40e97fb49b9eb1498111d7941ca3e63541a]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.907928    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.263993478s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/303abc540335a9ce7077fd21182845fbff2f06ed9eb1ac8af9effdfd048153b5 /var/lib/docker/containers/6544add2796f365d67d72fe283e083042aa2af82862eb6335295d228efa28d61]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.907845    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 7.630063774s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/a36c376a7ddd04c168822770866d8c34499ddec7e4039ada579b3d65adc57347 /var/lib/docker/containers/6a606a6c901f8373dff22f94ba77a24956a7b4eed3d0e550be168eeaeed86236]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.902731    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.259025553s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/0a7170e1a42bfa8b0112d8c7bb805da8e4778aa5ce90978d90ed5335929633ff /var/lib/docker/containers/1f68eaa59cab0a0bcdc087e25d18573044b599967a56867d189acd82bc19172b]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.871796    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.410999589s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/25ffbf8bd71e814af8991cc52499286d2d345b3f348fec9358ca366f341ed588 /var/lib/docker/containers/efe1969587c9b0412fe7f7c8c24bbe1326d46f576bddf12f88ae7cd406b6475d]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.871699    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.259940483s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/56909c00ec20b59c1fcb4988cd51fe50ebb467681f37bab3f9061d76993565bc /var/lib/docker/containers/a8d1df672c23313313b511389f6eeb44e78c3f9e4c346d214fc190695f270e5f]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.614518    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 5.982313751s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/cb057acc4f3a3e91470847f78ffd550b25a24605cec42ee080aaf193933968cf /var/lib/docker/containers/e755c4d88e4e5d4d074806e829b1e83fd52c8e2b1c01c27131222a40b0c6c10a]
Aug 22 04:00:35 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.837000    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 7.500602734s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/e9539d9569ccdcc79db1cd4add7036d70ad71391dc30ca16903bdd9bda4d0972 /var/lib/docker/containers/b0a7c955af1ed85f56aeaed1d787794d5ffd04c2a81820465a1e3453242c8a19]
Aug 22 04:00:34 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.836947    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 6.257091389s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/200f0f063157381d25001350c34914e020ea16b3f82f7bedf7e4b01d34e513a7 /var/lib/docker/containers/eca7504b7e24332381e459a2f09acc150a5681c148cebc5867ac66021cbe0435]
Aug 22 04:00:33 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:31.836787    1330 fsHandler.go:131] du and find on following dirs took 7.286756684s: [/var/lib/docker/overlay/37334712f505b11c7f0b27fb0580eadc0e79fc789dcfafbea1730efd500fb69c /var/lib/docker/containers/4858388c53032331868497859110a7267fef95110a7ab3664aa857a21ee02a3e]
Aug 22 04:00:22 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:21.999930    1330 qos_container_manager_linux.go:286] [ContainerManager]: Updated QoS cgroup configuration
Aug 22 04:00:20 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:19.598974    1330 server.go:794] GET /healthz: (136.991429ms) 200 [[curl/7.51.0] 127.0.0.1:35888]
Aug 22 04:00:10 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:08.024328    1330 server.go:794] GET /healthz: (36.191534ms) 200 [[curl/7.51.0] 127.0.0.1:35868]
Aug 22 04:00:05 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: I0822 04:00:05.861339    1330 server.go:794] GET /stats/summary/: (808.201834ms) 200 [[Go-http-client/1.1] 10.48.0.7:43022]
Aug 22 04:00:03 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: W0822 04:00:02.723586    1330 raw.go:87] Error while processing event ("/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/kube-logrotate.service": 0x40000100 == IN_CREATE|IN_ISDIR): inotify_add_watch /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/kube-logrotate.service: no such file or directory
Aug 22 04:00:03 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: W0822 04:00:02.723529    1330 raw.go:87] Error while processing event ("/sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/kube-logrotate.service": 0x40000100 == IN_CREATE|IN_ISDIR): inotify_add_watch /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/system.slice/kube-logrotate.service: no such file or directory
Aug 22 04:00:03 gke-app-node1 kubelet[1330]: W0822 04:00:02.622765    1330 raw.go:87] Error while processing event ("/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/kube-logrotate.service": 0x40000100 == IN_CREATE|IN_ISDIR): inotify_add_watch /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/system.slice/kube-logrotate.service: no such file or directory
```

---

`sudo dmesg -T`

```
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:31 2017] cbr0: port 4(vethd18b0189) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:31 2017] device vethd18b0189 left promiscuous mode
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:31 2017] cbr0: port 4(vethd18b0189) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:40 2017] cbr0: port 6(veth2985149d) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:40 2017] device veth2985149d left promiscuous mode
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:40 2017] cbr0: port 6(veth2985149d) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] cbr0: port 5(veth2a1d2827) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] device veth2a1d2827 left promiscuous mode
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] cbr0: port 5(veth2a1d2827) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] cbr0: port 2(vetha070fbca) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] device vetha070fbca left promiscuous mode
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] cbr0: port 2(vetha070fbca) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] cbr0: port 3(veth7e3e663a) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] device veth7e3e663a left promiscuous mode
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:42 2017] cbr0: port 3(veth7e3e663a) entered disabled state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:57 2017] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:57 2017] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:57 2017] device veth215e85fc entered promiscuous mode
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:57 2017] cbr0: port 1(veth215e85fc) entered forwarding state
[Tue Aug 22 04:17:57 2017] cbr0: port 1(veth215e85fc) entered forwarding state
[Tue Aug 22 04:18:12 2017] cbr0: port 1(veth215e85fc) entered forwarding state
```

---

And finally here we can see how the Kubernetes pods were killed around that time:

`docker ps -a`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS               NAMES
d7b59cd7116c        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                   k8s_POD_worker-deployment-3042507874-ghjpd_default_1de2291b-86ef-11e7-88da-42010a840211_0
e6f2563ac3c8        5e65193af899                               "/monitor --component"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                   k8s_prometheus-to-sd-exporter_fluentd-gcp-v2.0-5vlrc_kube-system_6cebabe5-84f9-11e7-88da-42010a840211_1
45d7886d0308        487e99ee05d9                               "/bin/sh -c '/run.sh "   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                   k8s_fluentd-gcp_fluentd-gcp-v2.0-5vlrc_kube-system_6cebabe5-84f9-11e7-88da-42010a840211_1
b5a5c5d085ac        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                   k8s_POD_fluentd-gcp-v2.0-5vlrc_kube-system_6cebabe5-84f9-11e7-88da-42010a840211_1
32dcd4d5847c        54d2a8698e3c                               "/bin/sh -c 'echo -99"   4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                   k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-gke-app-node1_kube-system_ed40100d42c9e285fa1f59ca7a1d8f8d_1
2d055d96b610        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 4 hours ago         Up 4 hours                                   k8s_POD_kube-proxy-gke-app-node1_kube-system_ed40100d42c9e285fa1f59ca7a1d8f8d_1
2be7aede380d        5e65193af899                               "/monitor --component"   2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago                       k8s_prometheus-to-sd-exporter_fluentd-gcp-v2.0-5vlrc_kube-system_6cebabe5-84f9-11e7-88da-42010a840211_0
7fd4d507ec64        54d2a8698e3c                               "/bin/sh -c 'echo -99"   2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago                       k8s_kube-proxy_kube-proxy-gke-app-node1_kube-system_ed40100d42c9e285fa1f59ca7a1d8f8d_0
cc615ec1e87c        efe10ee6727f                               "/bin/touch /run/xtab"   2 days ago          Exited (0) 2 days ago                        k8s_touch-lock_kube-proxy-gke-app-node1_kube-system_ed40100d42c9e285fa1f59ca7a1d8f8d_0
b0a7c955af1e        487e99ee05d9                               "/bin/sh -c '/run.sh "   2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago                       k8s_fluentd-gcp_fluentd-gcp-v2.0-5vlrc_kube-system_6cebabe5-84f9-11e7-88da-42010a840211_0
4858388c5303        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago                       k8s_POD_fluentd-gcp-v2.0-5vlrc_kube-system_6cebabe5-84f9-11e7-88da-42010a840211_0
6a606a6c901f        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0   "/pause"                 2 days ago          Exited (0) 4 hours ago                       k8s_POD_kube-proxy-gke-app-node1_kube-system_ed40100d42c9e285fa1f59ca7a1d8f8d_0
```

Our cluster is running kubernetes 1.7.3 both for master and the node pools, and it's on GKE (europe-west1-d zone).

Any help would be appreciated as we don't really know how to debug this problem further.

Comment: Are these at least n1-standard VMs? I have seen similar issues with shared vCPU instances.

Comment: They're n1-standard-2 VMs (2 vCPUs / 7.50 GB each).

Comment: You can refer to [this github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/28154) where similar issue was reported.

Comment: That github issue was actually created by me some time ago :)

Comment: I didn't realize that :), I'll do some research and see if I can find something useful for you.

Comment: Did you check the node logs to confirm if that was related to kernel panic due to out of memory OOM?